# Variable into a function

Tags: javascript

What am I missing here? It seems simple but I can't figure out why the 2nd alert shows "undefined" for the var id

```
<input type='button' class='getLoc' id=‘s13' value=‘s13’>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('.getLoc').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id); //<-- shows s13
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position,id){
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var lon = position.coords.longitude;
            alert(lat+","+lon+","+id); //<-- shows undefined for id
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

It's because you included `id` as a parameter to the callback function. That's the `id` that your `alert()` will refer to, and since only one argument is passed to the callback the value is `undefined`.

It should just be

```
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
```